# Matlab Structfun

Tags: r, matlab, struct, anonymous-function, sapply

I would like to know which function in R could be use to reproduce the structfun Matlab function:

```
x = real(x) #impose non-imaginary
                                             
# we actually want all the d_ij to be N*N, no N^2, so reshape:
z_d = structfun(@(x) reshape(x,z.N,z.N), z_d, 'Uniform',0); #this one
```

I would say `sapply()` but I did not succeed yet.

For more information, I am trying to translate Matlab code of a solveExactHat.m file from Balboni et al. 2021 paper.(https://www.openicpsr.org/openicpsr/project/130408/version/V1/view?path=/openicpsr/130408/fcr:versions/V1/Replication_Files&type=folder).

Comment: Most code you don’t want to translate line by line nor function by function. Figure out what the code is doing, then implement that concept in R. You’ll get better, faster and more maintainable code that way. Run the both pieces of code with the same input to ensure they produce the same output.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I did most part of the file but I am struggling on this and I don't have Matlab licence to check unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

with z_d being a vector,

```
z_d <- lapply(z_d, matrix, nrow=z$N, ncol=z$N)
```